# Breeze JS - Extending model from object graph

Tags: javascript, breeze

Currently I am able to extend the breeze model entity type of my Product entity using the following code:

```
    function registerProduct(metadataStore) {


        function Product(){}


        // description property
        Object.defineProperty(Product.prototype,'description', {
            // TODO: handle selected globalization language
            get: function () {
                return this.descripFr;
            }
        })

        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Product',Product);
    }
```

The issue I am having is using a property from the entity graph (in this case codeligne) in an extended property like so:

```
      Object.defineProperty(Product.prototype,'name', {
            get: function () {
                var codeligne = this.codeligne;
                var name = codeligne.ligne + '-' + this.codeprod;
                return name;
            }
        })
```

This throws an undefined exception for codeligne.ligne.
If I directly use the codeligne.ligne in an ng-repeat then the property is displayed properly so Breeze seems aware of it.

Any suggestions on how to use the codeligne graphed object when extending the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the entity represented by the "ligne" navigation property isn't loaded yet. You should check that it contains a value before referencing its properties.

```
  Object.defineProperty(Product.prototype, 'name', {
        get: function () {
            var codeligne = this.codeligne;

            if (!codeligne) {
                return null;
            }

            var name = codeligne.ligne + '-' + this.codeprod;
            return name;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After checking this, it seems you were right and for some reason the object graph was not loaded at the time I was extending the metadata, The fix I have for now is priming the application with related codelignes data on start. This seems to make Breeze aware of the property. Probably not the best solution but since that data is actually lookup data used elsewhere its an acceptable server round-trip in this case.